# const T& reference initialized to a temporary

Tags: c++, reference, constants

For the following code:

```
const int &Rtest = 0;
```

I'm unsure why g++ accepts this (would all compilers accept this?). I thought that reference types must reference objects, not arbitrary numbers, so what *is* Rtest at this point? How is it used in programming?

In contrast:

```
int &Rtest = 0;
```

Will *not* compile, and this makes sense to me, because reference types must reference objects.

So why does making the type reference `const int&` make it acceptable?

(I know `int` does not matter, this is just the type I happened to use.)

Comment: I apologize if this is a duplicate in advance, I could not find anything on this subject. Please post a link in either your answer or a comment if there is already an existing question and answer.
Thank you

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/506444/4342498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm unsure why g++ accepts this

Because the language specification tells it to. You can bind some kinds of reference to temporary objects. This is useful for passing temporaries by reference to functions; less useful, but still allowed, in other contexts like this.

> would all compilers accept this?

Yes, if they're conformant.

> what is `Rtest` at this point?

A reference to a temporary object of type `int` and value 0. The lifetime of the temporary is extended to match that of the reference.

Temporaries can only bind to `const` or *rvalue* references, which is why your `int&` example won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

because according to the C++ language rules, const reference CAN attach to temporary, but regular reference cant. 
that is why the first is ok , but the second isn't

```
const int &Rtest = 0;
```

here 0 is a temporary , that is why Rtest can reference it

```
int &Rtest = 0;
```

here 0 is a temporary , but Rtest is not a const reference  , so it can not reference it

interesting enough , VC++ does accept this syntax , although it's unclear rather it redeclares 0 as a variable or catches it as temporary

Comment: you're right , I fixed it

Comment: If you put warning level 4 VS should warn about the second case.